# Undo many times in Vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose state A in my document, I make change to B, C then D. 
Now I typed 'u', the state goes to C. 
I type 'u' again it goes back to D. (the second undo looks like redo to me).

In my understanding, undo means that I undo it once it will return to C, then undo again to it will return to B then undo again it will return to A.

Also, I know 'u3' can work here but in most cases I have no way to keep track of the number of state changes.

How can I achieve unlimited undo in Vim?

Comment: What is the actual question or problem here?

Comment: @SamProtsenko so what is the undo command similar to  "control Z" in Word?

Comment: You just need to exit from **insert** mode to **command** mode after each change (pressing `Esc`), and you will be able to make undo several times (just clicking `u`).

Comment: @SamProtsenko That is what I expected. But it keeps jump between state C and D every time I press 'u'. It doesn't go to B from C.

Comment: It sounds like you are in compatible mode. Create a `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have only 1 level of undo if you are in Vi compatible mode. You are missing out on a number of features by being in `'compatible'` mode. Just create a `~/.vimrc` file and you will automatically disable `'compatible'` mode.

What wonderful undo features do you get by using `'nocompatible'`?

- Unlimited undo
- Persistent undo
- Undo branches (like an undo tree)

Comment: Just a side note: check if you are in compatible mode, type `:set compatible?`.

Comment: In ubuntu 20.04, creating .vimrc does not implicitly set nocompatible, at least, when invoked as `vi`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the old vi undo/redo commands which allows undo (u) or redo (CTRL-R) to be pressed multiple times rather than browsing history to figure out the number of changes to undo.

The vi command uses the ~/.exrc file, not ~/.vimrc so just add "set nocompatible" to the file.

Note that I like using a single undo/redo to jump back to the last place in a file that I changed, and "u" followed by CTRL-R does the trick. And I can always hold down the "u" until all changes are undone including those I might have already saved.